# IOS using SDWebImage gives no setImageWithURL method error

Tags: ios, uiimageview, sdwebimage

Hi I am trying to use SDWebImage library for my project. I copied all the files. I have imported `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` But when I tried to use

```
[cell.mediaImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

it gives me error

```
No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:'
```

So I am doing anything wrong. What else things I have to use. Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have deprecated

```
[cell.mediaImg setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Use

```
 [cell.mediaImg sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

**and update sdwebimage files**

Comment: Hell man I spent 2 to 3 hours to figure it out. I thought I am not importing it properly. Thank you for saving a day. Such stupid mistake. Thank you.